# Forcing Diamond

Tags: set-theory, forcing

It is well known that adding a subset of a regular cardinal $\kappa$ with partial functions of size $< \kappa$ forces $\Diamond_\kappa$.  One can also see that if $S \in V$ is a stationary subset of $\kappa$, then $Add(\kappa,1)$ also forces $\Diamond(S)$.  Question: If $G \subseteq Add(\kappa,1)$ is generic, do we get $\Diamond(S)$ for all stationary $S \in V[G]$, $S \subseteq \kappa$?

Comment: Wait, for uncountable $\kappa$ doesn't the existence of a diamond sequence imply $\sf CH(\kappa)$? How does that fit with the first sentence?

Comment: Asaf, $\Diamond_\kappa$ implies $2^{<\kappa} = \kappa$. And yes, $Add(\kappa)$ does force this; if this instance of GCH fails then cardinals are collapsed.

Comment: Hm. I should *really* revise my "Forcing 101" material.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is yes, and the construction is essentially the same as for $\diamondsuit$.    Let $\dot S$ be a name for the stationary set, and define a diamond sequence $\langle A_\alpha\mid\alpha\in S\rangle$ as follows:  Let $f$ be the $Add(\kappa,1)$ function.   Suppose $\alpha\in S$.  Then let $\gamma$ be least such that $f\upharpoonright\gamma\Vdash\alpha\in\dot S$ and let $A_\alpha=\{\nu<\alpha\mid f(\gamma+\nu)=1\}$.

In answer to the comment, let $\dot C$ be a name for a club set $C$ and $\dot x$ the name for a subset of $\kappa$.  Let $C'$ be the set of $\nu\in C$ such that $f\upharpoonright\nu$ decides the value of $\dot x\cap\nu$ and forces $\nu$ is a limit point of $\dot C$ (and hence is in $\dot C$).   Then it is forced that $\dot C'$ is club in $V[\dot f]$, so there is a dense set of $q$ such that, setting $\eta=\operatorname{domain}(q)$, $q\Vdash\eta\in\dot C'$ and $q$ does not force $\eta\notin\dot S$.   Then let $q'\le q$ be of minimal length forcing $\eta\in\dot S$, and let $q''$ be $q'$ with the known value of $\dot x\cap \eta$ tacked onto the end.  Then $q''$ forces that $\dot A_\eta= \dot x\cap\eta$.

Comment: Can you explain why this works? Thanks.