# Details for Woodin's forcing argument for a saturated ideal from the Levy collapse

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing, large-cardinals

Theorem 2.65 in Woodin's [book](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2723878) shows that a saturated ideal on $\omega_1$ exists after Levy-collapsing a Woodin cardinal $\delta$ to $\omega_2$.  I am confused about the part of the argument where he shows that ideal he defines is a proper ideal.

Claim (2.2) on page 50 says we can find a countable structure $X \prec H_{\delta^+}$ and an $X$-generic condition $p$ such that for all inaccessible $\gamma \in X \cap \delta$ and $Col(\omega_1,<\gamma)$-names $\tau \in X$ for a semi-proper subset of $\mathcal P(\omega_1)/NS$, there is a $\sigma \in X$ such that $p \Vdash \sigma \in \tau$ and $p \Vdash X \cap \omega_1 \in \sigma$.  He says we construct this pair $(X,p)$ by an elementary chain.

Suppose $X_0 \prec H_{\delta^+}$ and $p_0 \restriction \gamma \in X_0$.  By definition of semi-proper, if $\tau \in X_0$ is as above, then $p_0 \Vdash_\gamma (\exists y \in \tau) Sk(X_0[G_\gamma] \cup \{ y \}) \cap \omega_1 = X_0[G_\gamma] \cap \omega_1$ and $X_0[G_\gamma] \cap \omega_1 \in y$.  The problem I have is: How do we choose a *name* for $y$ with a similar property?  There is a name $\sigma$ such that $p_0$ forces $\sigma^G$ witnesses the above property of $y$ in $V[G_\gamma]$, but could it be that $Sk(X_0 \cup \{ \sigma \}) \cap \omega_1 \not= X_0 \cap \omega_1$?

Or perhaps there is a quite different strategy for building the elementary chain.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: The argument Hugh refers to can be seen in (more) detail at the beginning of Paul Larson's book on stationary tower forcing.

Comment: Thanks Andres, but could you be a little more specific?

Comment: And could you let me know if I am on the right track for reconstructing the details?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo, I do not see how anything in the first chapter addresses my question.

Comment: Yes, nothing there is explicitly what you need. But the construction is essentially as in 1.1.18-1.1.22, iterated. If I can think of a more explicit place, I'll post a reference.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo, I am probably missing something.  I am well aware of the lemmas you mention and how to prove them, but I do not see how to apply them to this specific forcing question.  (i.e. Can we choose the index of an appropriate name for a stationary set from some measure-1 set?)   If you could explain how this application works in an answer, it would be very helpful to me.

Comment: I think you can find an argument for your question (or something similar) in the following paper "[A proof of the $\Sigma^2_1$-absoluteness theorem](http://people.math.yorku.ca/ifarah/Ftp/15f05-abs.pdf)"

Comment: At present I don't see how to use Farah's arguments to fill in the gaps in Woodin's proof.  It seems like Farah defines the ideal differently in order to anticipate the kinds of problems that could arise when working with Woodin's definition.  Woodin's argument seems overall simpler than Farah's, so I hope I can see the details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Woodin's argument is wrong.  Let us state his definition of the ideal.  Assume $G \subseteq \mathrm{Col}(\omega_1,<\delta)$ is generic over $V$.

> Let $I_0 \in V[G]$ be the set of $A \subseteq \omega_1$ such that for some $f : \omega_1 \to \mathcal{P}(\omega_1) \setminus NS$,
>
> (1.1) $A = \{ \beta < \omega_1 : \beta \notin f(\alpha)$ for all $\alpha < \beta \}$
>
> (1.2) If $\mathcal A = \{ f(\alpha) : \alpha < \omega_1 \}$, then for some $\gamma < \delta$, $\gamma$ is strongly inaccessible in $V$, $\mathcal A \in V[G \cap V_\gamma]$ and $\mathcal A$ is semiproper in $V[G \cap V_\gamma]$.
>
> Let $I$ be the normal ideal generated by $I_0$.

As stated earlier in the chapter, Foreman, Magidor, and Shelah [proved](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=924672) that whenever $\delta$ is supercompact and $G \subseteq \mathrm{Col}(\omega_1,<\delta)$ is generic, then in $V[G]$, every maximal antichain in $\mathcal P(\omega_1)/NS$ is semiproper.  Actually only something like $\beth_4(\delta)$-supercompactness is used.

Assume $\kappa < \delta$ are both Woodin and $\beth_4(\cdot)$-supercompact.  Let $G_\delta \subseteq \mathrm{Col}(\omega_1,<\delta)$ be generic and let $G_\kappa = G_\delta \cap V_\kappa$.   Let $I_\kappa \in V[G_\kappa]$ and $I_\delta \in V[G_\delta]$ be the ideals as above, and note that $I_\kappa \subseteq I_\delta$.

By a well-known forcing argument (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/125308/forcing-diamond)), $V[G_\kappa]$ satisfies $\Diamond(S)$ for every stationary $S \subseteq \omega_1$.  This easily implies that $NS \restriction S$ is not $\omega_2$-saturated for any stationary $S$.  In $V[G_\kappa]$, the set of stationary $S$ which are in $I_\kappa$ is dense in $\mathcal{P}(\omega_1)/NS$.  This is because otherwise there would be some $S$ such that $I_\kappa \restriction S = NS \restriction S$.

Thus there is a maximal antichain of stationary sets $\mathcal A \subseteq I_\kappa$ in $V[G_\kappa]$, and it is semiproper.  In $V[G_\delta]$ there is an enumeration $\{ S_\alpha : \alpha < \omega_1 \}$ of $\mathcal A$, and the diagonal union $\nabla S_\alpha$ is put into the dual filter to $I_\delta$.  But since $I_\kappa \subseteq I_\delta$ and $I_\delta$ is normal in $V[G_\delta]$, $\nabla S_\alpha \in I_\delta$.  Thus $I_\delta$ is not a proper ideal.

Comment: There's some unicode issue in the block quote. (I see three "characters", after $A$ in the first line, and after "some" and before "is strongly" in the third line.)

Comment: It doesn't show up for me, but I tweaked it a bit. Maybe a Mac vs PC thing. Do you still see it? Feel free to fix it.

Comment: I removed that, sorry in advance if something got messed up.